# tkinter only refresh visible frame using after

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am writing a GUI that takes and displays live data from multiple sensors. I have different frames in my GUI between which you can navigate. At this moment every frame is refreshing at 25Hz using an 'after' method call.

I think (but I'm not sure) that the frames are also refreshing even when hidden for the user (when the user is seeing another frame). This of course eats resources, so I was wondering how to only refresh a frame when you are looking at it?

Comment: Use a tracking variable. When frame is hidden make sure this variable is updated and in your method that runs the after statement you add an `if` statement that first checks to see if the frame is hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example that shows how one could track what frame is currently the top frame and only update that frames data.

This is not the only way and probably not even the best way but its should serve to give you an starting point.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
timer1 = 0
timer2 = 0
frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame2 = tk.Frame(root)
frame2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
frame1.tkraise()

current_active_frame = frame1

lbl1 = tk.Label(frame1, text='Active Counter at: 0')
lbl2 = tk.Label(frame2, text='Active Counter at: 0')
lbl1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
lbl2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
tk.Button(frame1, text='Switch to frame 2', command=lambda: raise_frame(frame2)).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')
tk.Button(frame2, text='Switch to frame 1', command=lambda: raise_frame(frame1)).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')


def raise_frame(frame):
    global current_active_frame
    frame.tkraise()
    current_active_frame = frame


def update_while_active():
    global timer1, timer2
    if current_active_frame == frame1:
        print('frame1')
        timer1 += 1
        lbl1.config(text='Active Counter at: {}'.format(timer1))
    if current_active_frame == frame2:
        print('frame2')
        timer2 += 1
        lbl2.config(text='Active Counter at: {}'.format(timer2))
    root.after(1000, update_while_active)

update_while_active()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! So simple, weird that I couldn't find this online. I did not test it yet in my code, but the example works so it should work with my code as well.

Comment: I tested it with my code and it works perfect. Thanks again!